# Django: create a comment form when user is authenticated

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I'm creating a simple blog application. A user is logged in this application while He/She can comment any post on my blog application. But cant impletement that idea. 
This is my models.py file

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

from user.models import CustomUser

from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse

class BlogPost(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    blog_title=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    blog_description=models.TextField()
    blog_pub=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    blog_update=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.blog_title


    def get_absolute_url(self):

        return reverse('blog:blog_post', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})




class Comment(models.Model):
    blogpost=models.ForeignKey(BlogPost, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    comment=models.CharField(max_length=300)
    author=models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True, null=True)
    author_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='anonymous', verbose_name=("user name"))
    comment_pub = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    comment_update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('blog:home', kwargs={'pk':self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.comment
```

This is views.py file

```
class BlogPostSingle(DetailView, FormView):
    model=BlogPost
    template_name='blog/blog_post_single.html'
    #fields = ['blog_title']
    form_class = CreateCommentForm
    success_url = '/blog/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

this is my forms.py file

```
class CreateCommentForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Comment
        fields = ('comment', 'blogpost')
```

and this is my html file and forms section

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <h5>Hi, {{user.name}} leave your comment now</h5>
        <form action="" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %} {{form.as_p}}

            <input type="submit" value="Submit comment">
        </form>
        {% else %}
        <p>You're not logged in this site, please  <a href="{% url 'login' %}">log</a> in for comment </p>
        {% endif %}
```

**My target Idea:** Just user logged on my blog application. He can be able to comment any post on my blog application. And my **Comment** Models   contain two forignkey field.

Comment: You do not seem to describe what does not work in what you implemented, so it's difficult to try and help you...

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the user to your view's context, so it will be available in the template:

```
class BlogPostSingle(DetailView, FormView):
    ...
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['user'] = self.request.user
        return context
```

on `get_context_data` see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview

on `self.request` see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#dynamic-filtering